# grep - match word and nothing after it

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file in the following format (thousands of lines & tab delimited):

```
Gnl3l   3'UTR    
Smap1   5'UTR||3'UTR    
D4Wsu53e    CDS||5'UTR||3'UTR    
Mecp2   3'UTR    
Mecp2   3'UTR
```

I want to return all lines that contain ONLY `"3'UTR"` from the second tab. Desired output:

```
Gnl3l   3'UTR    
Mecp2   3'UTR    
Mecp2   3'UTR
```

Any thoughts on a `grep`/regex to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `awk` here since using `awk` you can match a particular field easily without using complex regex:

```
awk -v s="3'UTR" '$2==s' file
Gnl3l   3'UTR
Mecp2   3'UTR
Mecp2   3'UTR
```

However here is a `grep` command that will also work but I prefer awk:

```
grep "\t3'UTR" file
Gnl3l   3'UTR
Mecp2   3'UTR
Mecp2   3'UTR
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a regex here, use something like this:

```
grep "(.*)\t3'UTR$"
```

This regex says that there can stand anything on the beginning (`(.*)`), followed by a tab (`\t` - you could also use all whitespaces `\s`) and the `3'UTR`. After that, the line must end (`$`).

Note that the `(.*)` is not needed, but if you want to use the regex away from grep you'll find environments where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E "^\S+\s+3'UTR$" file
```

Or

```
grep "^[^\t]\+\t\+3'UTR$" file
```

Output:

```
Gnl3l   3'UTR
Mecp2   3'UTR
Mecp2   3'UTR
```